# controller undefined angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner in angularJs. As I was trying to build a sample app, I am getting this following error

`controller undefined angularjs`

```
<div ng-controller="listCtrl">
        {{2+3}}
    </div>
```

It is not printing the `{{2+3}}` expression on browser but when I remove the `ng-controller` tag from the div it prints the result is `5` which is correct.

I have linked all necessary scripts in html file.

here is my controller code

```
(function(){

  angular.module("myApp").controller("listCtrl", Listcontroller);

    function Listcontroller($scope){
      $scope.dummyData = "hello word";
    }

})();
```

Comment: What does the actual error say? That error message doesn't make sense

Comment: Since your application is angular application, it will evaluate the expression inside {{}}, so with or without controller, it would give you 5.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are missing value of `ng-app` directive. like below

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="listCtrl">
     {{2+3}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, please note, that if you haven't created your module (`myApp`) first, then you need to do that by doing this `angular.module("myApp", [])` before referring your `controller` file or within `controller` file.

```
(function(){

  angular.module("myApp", []).controller("listCtrl", Listcontroller);

    function Listcontroller($scope){
      $scope.dummyData = "hello word";
    }

})();
```

Comment: I have already created module in different file called app.js

Comment: Yes. Added it in html tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an empty array as argument in angular.module()
For example-

```
(function(){

  angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("listCtrl", Listcontroller);

    function Listcontroller($scope){
      $scope.dummyData = "hello word";
    }

})();
```